# A function with datetime type

Tags: php, datetime

I have a problem and can't find any solution.
I'm trying to make a page to add shows to a specific movie in a specific theater and in specific time. I need to make a function to check the time of the previous or next show and check the availability to add a show for a movie with a specific duration

ex: movie duration 2 hrs
show 1 : 1 PM
When adding a show at 2 PM, it will give an error because the show of 1 PM didn't yet finish.

**I believe my problem is with the datetime format!! cause I'm not getting an error...the page is working but the data type input isn't correct**

The code:

```
    require('classes/show_class.php');

    $valid_show = show::check_time_validity($showdatetime,$movieid, $theaterid);

    if( $valid_show !== true )
    {
        echo $valid_show['error'];
        exit;
    }

    $querycinema=mysql_query(
        "SELECT show.show_datetime, show.theater_id, show.movie_id, theater.theater_name, movie.movie_name 
        FROM `show` 
        JOIN theater ON theater.theater_id = show.theater_id
        JOIN movie ON movie.movie_id = show.movie_id                            
        WHERE show.show_datetime='$showdatetime' AND show.theater_id='$theaterid' AND show.movie_id='$movieid'"
    );

    $checkcinema = mysql_num_rows( $querycinema );

    if( $checkcinema != 0 )
    { 
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $querycinema );
        echo "Sorry, ".$showdatetime." is already been scheduled for movie ".$data['movie_name']." in theater ".$data['theater_name']."."; 
    }
    else
    {   echo "$selected_show_time";

        $insert_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `show` (show_datetime, movie_id, theater_id) VALUES ('$showdatetime','$movieid', '$theaterid')");

        if( $insert_user )
        {
            header("Refresh: 0;url=listallshows.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error in registration".mysql_error();
        }
    }
}
```

And the show_class.php function:

```
public static function check_time_validity($show_datetime,$movie_id, $theater_id)
{
$show_date = date($show_datetime);

$query = "
    (
        SELECT show_datetime 
        FROM  `show` 
        WHERE movie_id = {$movie_id} AND theater_id = {$theater_id} AND DATE( show_datetime ) =  '{$show_date}' AND  '{$show_datetime}' >= show_datetime
        ORDER BY show_datetime DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT show_datetime
        FROM  `show` 
        WHERE movie_id = {$movie_id} AND theater_id = {$theater_id} AND DATE( show_datetime ) = '{$show_date}' AND  '{$show_datetime}' <= show_datetime
        ORDER BY show_datetime ASC 
        LIMIT 1
    )";

$results = mysql_query( $query );

$selected_show_time = strtotime( $show_datetime );

$show_times = array();

while( $show = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results ) )
{
    $show_time = strtotime( $show['show_datetime'] );

    if( $selected_show_time == $show_time )
    {
        return array( 'error' => 'Datetime inserted already exists' );
    }

    if( $selected_show_time > $show_time )
    {
        $show_times['time_before'] = $show_time;
    }
    elseif( $selected_show_time < $show_time )
    {
        $show_times['time_after'] = $show_time;
    }
}

$movie = new movie($movie_id);
$movie_duration = $movie->duration;

$can_begin = true;
$can_finish = true;
$errorMessage = array();

if( $show_times['time_before'] )
{
    $finish_time = $show_times['time_before'] + $movie_duration;

    if( ( $selected_show_time - $finish_time ) < '15' )
    {
        $can_begin = false;
        $errorMessage = array( 'error' => 'The datetime selected is in conflict with the previous show' );  echo "$selected_show_time"; echo"$finish_time";exit;

    }
}

if( $show_times['time_after'] )
{
    $finish_selected_time = $selected_show_time + $movie_duration;

    if( ( $show_times['time_after'] - $finish_selected_time  ) < '15' )
    {
        $can_finish = false;
        $errorMessage = array( 'error' => 'The datetime selected is in conflict with the next show' );
    }
}
if( $can_begin && $can_finish )
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return $errorMessage;
}
    }
```

Hoping for any help thank you..

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: no error exactly...but I put wrong show datetime and the show is added wwithout any error

Comment: So your problem is on the validation of previous time.

Comment: I would recommend you using prepare & bind statements to protect yourself from SQL injections. Instead of putting your variables right into the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that you use date() on your show_datetime variable and try to compare it to the DATE(show_datetime) in the query.
While DATE() in mysql extracts the date part, date() in PHP does not do this.
Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to see how date() works in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most critical problem that I see is that you don't have a `film length column` or `film end time`... which is why you dont get the expected result.

Also it would be great if you get used to [prepare and bind](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) queries to protect yourself from SQL injections.

My little 2 cents of help would be:

First separate the `show_datetime` queries and limit it to 1. So then you have just the 2 closes first values. Then what you need to do is to create a function that tells you which one of these values(dates) is closes to your value (date).

```
function closest($array, $number) {

    sort($array);
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($a >= $number) return $a;
    }
    return end($array) // or return NULL;
}
```

that would then tell you the closest movie time to your given time... but you still miss the film `length value` you are never passing that on your function nor I can see it on your db query or manipulation

```
$valid_show = show::check_time_validity($showdatetime,$movieid, $theaterid);
```

I guess is imposible to assess if they overlap if you dont have `finish time` or `film lenght`